# How to get rid of duplicate by sql query

Tags: duplicates

I have a database table which stores email address data, date of join and a column newsletter (yes/no). However, there are lots of duplicate email addresses with different dates and values in the newsletter column. I need to write sql query that would exclude those emails (records) with more recent dates and leave only the records with the oldest dates:

```html
EMAIL DATEJOIN NEWSLETTER
zzzzzzzzzz_@hotmail.com 02/03/2015 0
zzzzzzzzzz_@hotmail.com 30/06/2015 1
vishythamack@hotmail.com 22/09/2012 1
vishysblue@gmail.com 19/09/2012 1
yann-o@hotmail.fr 07/07/2015 0
yannnsheng@hotmail.com 02/03/2015 0
yannnsheng@hotmail.com 22/09/2012 1
thilaxanschool@gmail.com 18/09/2013 1
```

```html
What I need After Query 

EMAIL DATEJOIN NEWSLETTER
zzzzzzzzzz_@hotmail.com 02/03/2015 0
vishythamack@hotmail.com 22/09/2012 1
vishysblue@gmail.com 19/09/2012 1
yann-o@hotmail.fr 07/07/2015 0
yannnsheng@hotmail.com 22/09/2012 1
thilaxanschool@gmail.com 18/09/2013 1
```

I tried to use the following:

```html
SELECT [EMAIL]
      ,min([DATEJOIN]) as [DATEJOIN]
   , [NEWSLETTER]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[first]
  group by [EMAIL], [NEWSLETTER]
```

But it doesn't work. I need to decide what to do with the Newsletter field. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend just finding everything with duplicate values and deleting the old ones using a script of some sort.

SELECT EMAIL
  FROM [test].[dbo].[first]
  having count(*) > 1

If you don't want to do that you could do something like:

SELECT a.* from first a 
inner join (select email, min(datejoin) as join from first group by email) b
b on a.email = b.email and a.datejoin = b.datejoin

which should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. SELECT a.* from first a inner join (select email, min(datejoin) as join from first group by email) b b on a.email = b.email and a.datejoin = b.datejoin works.

Comment: However, I figured out that there are records with email addresses where datejoin field is completely the same. In this case I have to use Tableau countd function then to exclude them